# Property of the field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field and $A$ a subring of $K$ with the following
>   property: for every finite family $(\xi_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ of
>   elements of $K$ there exists $\gamma\in A-\{0\}$ such that
>   $\gamma\xi_i\in A$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ (a hypothesis which is always
>   satisfied when $A$ is abelian and $K$ is the field of fractions of
>   $A$).

First of all, if $A$ is only nonzero and abelian, then it is not necessarily an integral domain; therefore, how can it possess a field of fractions $K$? Surely they mean that $A$ is an integral domain and not only an abelian and nonzero ring, correct?

Now, if $K$ is the field of fractions of $A$, then $A$ can be identified a with its image in $K$: i.e. $A$ is a nonzero subring of the abelian field $K$. Therefore there exist $\gamma\in A$ such that $\gamma\ne0$. But why does it follow that $\gamma\xi_i\in A$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$?

Comment: It says “subring of a field” and that trivially cannot have nonzero zero divisors..

Comment: Right, so $A$ is necessarily an integral domain.

Comment: clarification: are fields necessarily abelian in your text?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen they are not.

Comment: Then perhaps the part in parentheses is less confusing when formulated like this: "(a condtion that is always satisfied when the subring $A$ is abelien and there is no proper subfield of $K$ that contains $A$)"

Comment: Hint: the hypothesis is equivalent to: $\gamma$ is a common denominator for the fractions (which always exists for a finite set of fractions, e.g the product of the denominators).

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I just don't understand why $\gamma\xi_i$ are elements of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Notational Reminder: "field" here means "skew field", i.e., multiplication need not be abelian. Also, "ring" means "ring with $1$" (or at least "ring with more than one element").*

**Claim.** Let $K$ be a field, $A$ a an abelian subring and assume that there is no field $L$ with $A\subseteq L\subsetneq K$.
Let $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n\in K$. Then there exists $\gamma\in A\setminus\{0\}$ with $\gamma \xi_i\in A$ for $1\le i\le n$.

*Proof.* Let $$L=\{\,\xi\in K\mid\exists \gamma\in A\setminus\{0\}\colon \gamma\xi\in A\,\}.$$
Clearly, $A\subseteq  L$ (here we use $A\setminus\{0\}\ne\emptyset$).
Assume $\xi_1,\xi_2\in L$. Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2\in A\setminus\{0\}$ with $\gamma_1\xi_1,\gamma_1\xi_2\in A$.
Then $\gamma:=\gamma_1\gamma_2\in A\setminus\{0\}$ and
$$ \gamma(\xi_1-\xi_2)=\gamma_2\gamma_1\xi_1-\gamma_1\gamma_2\xi_2\in A$$
so that $L$ is a subgroup of $K$ under addition.
Also, 
$$\gamma\xi_1\xi_2=\gamma_2\gamma_1\xi_1\xi_2=\gamma_1\xi_1\gamma_2\xi_2\in A$$
so that $L$ is closed under multiplication.
Finally, if $\xi_1\ne 0$, then $\gamma_1\xi_1\in A\setminus\{0\}$ and
$$ \gamma_1\xi\cdot\xi_1^{-1}=\gamma_1\in A.$$
It follows that $L$ is a subfield of $K$ and contains $A$. By assumption $L=K$. This solves the claim for $n=1$.
Now let $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n\in K$. As just seen, there exist $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n\in A\setminus\{0\}$ with $\gamma_i\xi_i\in A$ for  $1\le i\le n$. Then $\gamma:=\gamma_1\cdots\gamma_n\in A\setminus\{0\}$ and
$$ \gamma\xi_i=\gamma_1\cdots\gamma_{i-1}\gamma_{i+1}\cdots\gamma_n\cdot\gamma_i\xi_i\in A,$$
as was to be shown. $\square$